# Disable kindo autocomplete while processing information in database

Tags: jquery, sql-server, kendo-ui

I have my Kindo AutoComplete within a helper function. When I make a search and click one the of AutoComplete results, a function is fired up which pulls in data from the data source. It takes a while for the information to be returned and displayed on the page. During that process I need the AutoComplete to be disabled and it must be enabled back once the data is processed and displayed. Basically, I need to prevent the user from making a new search while the first selected request is being processed.

Answer (score 0):

The Kendo AutoComplete has a method to enable or disable.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/autocomplete#methods-enable

From the linked example:

```
<input id="autocomplete" />
<script>
$("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete();
var autocomplete = $("#autocomplete").data("kendoAutoComplete");
autocomplete.enable(false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`requestStart`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#events-requestStart) and [`requestEnd`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#events-requestEnd) for controlling when to [`enable`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/autocomplete#configuration-enable) or *disable* (`enable(false)`) the AutoComplete. This event handlers are part of the DataSource.

Example:

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read : {
            url: "..."
        }
    },
    requestStart: function (e) {
        ac.enable(false);
    },
    requestEnd: function(e) { 
        ac.enable(true);
    }
});
```

Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/nQ5JJ/

**EDIT:** If what you want is to prevent to use the AutoComplete once the user picks an option, then you should disable the autocomplete when [`close`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/autocomplete#events-close) event is fired and enable again when that new data is available.

```
var ac = $("input").kendoAutoComplete({
    dataSource: states,
    close : function (e) {
        // Disable autocomplete while we read from `ds` DataSource
        ac.enable(false);
        // Trigger ope
        ds.read();
    }
}).data("kendoAutoComplete");
```

and when the `read` operation finishes, then you enable the autocomplete again:

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read : {
            url : "...";
        }
    },
    requestEnd: function(op) {
        ac.enable(true);
    }
});
```

Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/nQ5JJ/1/

Comment: I don't need to disable the control when the control itself is making a request. There is a database request that is kicked off after a selection is made from the results that autocomplete brought in. The process that is taking a while is outside of the AutoComplete control. I need to disable the control while a external process is running

Comment: Maybe I did not understand you... What my answer does is preventing that the user keeps typing once you request something to the service and while the answer is not available. If you check the JSFiddle you will see that while there is no answer (I've simulated it with a timeout) the user cannot issue a second request basically because he/she cannot type more. So, what is what different in you question? That you want to disable it the users selects an option?